# UVa 10461 Difference Java Solution got Runtime Error

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve [UVa 10461 Difference](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1402) problem using Java and I am pretty sure of the logic of my code because I actually submitted this logic in C++ and got accepted but when I was trying to submit it using Java, I got Runtime error.

The problem asks to calculate the maximum possible difference among all possible completion times of a particular job.

Any ideas

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(bufferReader.readLine());

        int v = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        int e = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        int count = 1;

        while (v != 0 || e != 0) {
            int[] jobs = new int[v];
            List<List<Integer>> parents = new ArrayList<>(v);
            List<List<Integer>> children = new ArrayList<>(v);

            int sum = 0;

            st = new StringTokenizer(bufferReader.readLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
                jobs[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                parents.add(new ArrayList<>());
                children.add(new ArrayList<>());
                sum += jobs[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
                st = new StringTokenizer(bufferReader.readLine());
                int from = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1;
                int to = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1;
                children.get(from).add(to);
                parents.get(to).add(from);
            }

            st = new StringTokenizer(bufferReader.readLine());
            int q = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

            st = new StringTokenizer(bufferReader.readLine());
            out.println("Case #" + count++ + ":");
            while (q-- > 0) {
                int cur = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1;
                int max = sum - getJobTime(cur, parents, jobs) - jobs[cur];
                int min = getJobTime(cur, children, jobs);
                out.println(max - min);
            }

            out.println();
            out.flush();

            bufferReader.readLine();

            st = new StringTokenizer(bufferReader.readLine());
            v = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            e = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }

        bufferReader.close();
        out.close();
    }

    public static int getJobTime(int job, List<List<Integer>> dependencies, int[] jobs) {
        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        List<Integer> curDependencies = dependencies.get(job);

        for (Integer item : curDependencies) {
            q.offer(item);
            set.add(item);
        }

        int count = 0;

        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            int cur = q.poll();
            count += jobs[cur];
            curDependencies = dependencies.get(cur);

            for (Integer item : curDependencies) {
                if (!set.contains(item)) {
                    q.offer(item);
                    set.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain your logic as well

Comment: "Next line has an
integer q which denotes the number of queries to answer which is followed by q integers x (1 ≤ x ≤ v)". Are each of the q integers in a line by itself? The problem statement does not explicitly say that.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur
simply for each node I build up two lists the first one is the children list of this node and the second one is the parents of this node. And for each query, I use BFS to get the total job times of the parent nodes and the children nodes

Comment: @MAK I changed it to check if the string tokenizer has more elements before reading a new line:
```
while (q-- > 0) {
                if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    int cur = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1;
                    int max = sum - getJobTime(cur, parents, jobs) - jobs[cur];
                    int min = getJobTime(cur, children, jobs);
                    out.println(max - min);
                } else {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(bufferReader.readLine());
                }
            }
```